# Merging multiple table in one postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I inherit a database with a specific schema that have 288 tables. These tables have all *exactly* the same column name. I would like to merge all these 288 tables in 1.

My first try was to `CREATE TABLE AS` :

```
CREATE TABLE bigTable AS SELECT X.* FROM (SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename LIKE '%xxx') AS X
```

But this obviously doesn't work.

So I tried with a plpgsql script:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
   r RECORD;
BEGIN
   FOR r in (SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename LIKE '%iti') LOOP
     INSERT INTO xxx(gid, shape_len, geom)
     SELECT * FROM r;
   END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

But it tells me that it doesn't know what `r` is.

I think I'm missing something about how pg handle this kind of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating syntax dynamically, use `Execute` command that performs SQL supplied with string data.
I've just made 3 tables with example values and made 4th table that has been filled using this statement

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    tbl_name text;
BEGIN
    FOR tbl_name IN     (SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename LIKE 'table%') LOOP
    execute 'INSERT INTO table4 select * FROM '||tbl_name;
    END LOOP;

END;
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this shell script to fetch all the tables and insert into the new table

```
#!/bin/bash

psql **DATABASE_NAME** -c "select tablename from pg_tables where 
schemaname='public'" | sed 1,2d | head -n -2 > hello.out

while read line;
do
psql **DATABASE_NAME** -c "insert into **TABLE_NAME** (select * from  $line )"
done < hello.out
```